"No compatible GPU's found for cycles" Linux
I'm new to blender (started in 4.1) and when 4.2 releases, I noticed an HUGE perfomance drop in rendered and material preview view. I saw on reddit that I just had to go to Preferencies, System, Cycle Render Devices and change "none" to CUDA/Optix, but when I try to select them, this message show up:
Can Anyone help please (I'm on linux)
Thanks :)

So, Blender 4.1 was okay, no error message? But now in Blender 4.2 you get this error message?

Uh no I don't remember this happening in 4.1

What are your computer specs, do you have a CUDA compatible GPU? CUDA settings only affect rendering with Cycles if you experience slowdowns in material preview, this may well be caused by the new EEVEE next real time ray tracing, and has nothing to do with CUDA.

What GPU do you have? where did you get Blender (steam, official site, snap, flatpak)

Are you running Wayland or X11? I've found X11 to still be working better. Also, have you got the official Nvidia drivers installed?

Try closing Blender and running the following command on your terminal:
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm && sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
your Graphics card should now be selectable under CUDA/Optix. That did the trick for me.
